# How to use mutable data in future flutter?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-futurebuilder

How can I use the MutableData? or is it already deprecated? I am currently creating a user information that will be send to firebase realtime database.

```
  addUser(User user) async {
    final TransactionResult transactionResult =
        await _counterRef.runTransaction((MutableData mutableData) async {
      mutableData.value = (mutableData.value ?? 0) + 1;

      return mutableData;
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. What isn't working about the code you shared?

Comment: the problem is in here, It was an error `` await _counterRef.runTransaction((MutableData mutableData) async {
      mutableData.value = (mutableData.value ?? 0) + 1;
      return mutableData;``

Comment: What is the error then? Note that an interactive Q&A is highly inefficient on Stack Overflow, so I recommend reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).